# Project specific security settings page never displays from browser

Tags: azure-devops

When I try to load the project specific security settings page, it just spins.  Does it work for you guys?

https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/project/_settings/security

I can get to the collection level.

thanks

dean

Comment: Have you tried https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_security instead? It seems to end up on this URL if click to that page in UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems azure AD is down. Funny, my first day switching to "the cloud" and it is down...go figure :)

Comment: It is working for me now by using  https://xxx.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_security

Comment: @dean You could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.